# In web3.js how do I get the original input parameters to a call into the callback return?

Tags: web3js

Using this example from the web3 docs, how would I get the original passed parameter "123" when the async .then is called?

myContract.methods.myMethod(123).call({from: '0xde0B295669a9FD93d5F28D9Ec85E40f4cb697BAe'})
.then(function(result){

<I want to get the value '123'>
...
});

I could change the contract return to include the information yet it seems I'm overlooking something obvious.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access the original passed parameter "123" inside the .then callback function then you will need to capture the value. This code may help you.

```
const myValue = 123;

myContract.methods.myMethod(myValue).call({from: '0xde0B295669a9FD93d5F28D9Ec85E40f4cb697BAe'})
  .then(function(result) {
    
    console.log("myValue:", myValue); // here you can access the original passed parameter "123" 

    console.log("Result from contract:", result); // you can also access the result returned by the contract

  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.error("Error:", error);
  });
```

In this code the myValue variable is defined outside the scope of the .then callback and javascript functions have access to variables in their outer scope hence you can access myValue within the .then callback